# Irrotational fields and divergence

Tags: vector-fields, divergence-operator

Let $F,G$ be $C^1$ vector fields from $\mathbb R^n$ in itself. The condition
$$\int_{\partial A}F\cdot \nu_A\ d\sigma=\int_{\partial A} G\cdot \nu_A\ d\sigma$$
for every bounded domain $A$ whose boundery is $C^1$ does not imply that $F-G$ is constant.

> Prove that if $F$ and $G$ are irrotational and bounded then $F-G$ must be constant.

Until now I've obtained that $\int_A div (F-G)=0$, so $div (F-G)=0$ (correct?).

General suggestions about properties of irrotational and zero-divergence vector fields are welcome too.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You meant $G\cdot \nu_A$ in the second integral?

Comment: Also unless $n=3$, I'm not sure what you mean by irrotational, since the only definition I know involves the curl.

Comment: There is a generalisation of that definition which makes use of differential forms. In this context I assume the text just means "$F=\nabla V$" where $V$ is a $C^2(\mathbb R^n)$ function.

Comment: @W.Rether ah, that makes sense.

Comment: Also that should probably be $\int_A \mathrm{div}(F-G)=0$ since I'm assuming you got it from Stokes' theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the notation $H=F-G$ we have

1. $H$ is [curl free and divergence free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_vector_field) $\implies$ $H=\nabla \phi$ where $\phi$ is a harmonic function in $\Bbb R^n$.
2. Partial derivatives of a harmonic function are harmonic functions (partial derivation and Laplace operator commute as harmonic functions are [sufficiently smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Regularity_theorem_for_harmonic_functions)), hence, the components of $H$ are harmonic too. They are also bounded in $\Bbb R^n$ by the assumption.
3. [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville.27s_theorem) says now that the components of $H$ must be constant functions.